# Como deletar linha com informação após uma linha em branco no meio?

Tags: vba, macro

Estou rodando uma macro para importar dados txt.
Porem esta macro está trazendo a informação abaixo após uma linha branca

> (9 rows(s) affected)

A informação dos dados está correta, porém tem esta linha que preciso que a macro delete.

Isto via código VBA.

**Editado:** código da macro *baseado nos comentários*

```
    Sub XPTO()    
        With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= "TEXT;Z:\42\Promessas_diarias_AES_RC_20150304_210000.txt", Destination:= Range(Selection.Address))
           .Name = "Promessas_diarias_AES_RC_20150304_210000" 
           .FieldNames = True 
           .RowNumbers = False 
           .FillAdjacentFormulas = False 
           .PreserveFormatting = True 
           .RefreshOnFileOpen = False 
           .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells 
           .SavePassword = False 
           .SaveData = True 
           .AdjustColumnWidth = True 
           .RefreshPeriod = 0 
           .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False 
           .TextFilePlatform = 1252 
           .TextFileStartRow = 5 
           .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited 
           .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote 
           .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False 
           .TextFileTabDelimiter = True 
           .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = True 
           .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False 
           .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False 
           .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1) 
           .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True 
           .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False 
       End With 
       ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=6 
       Range("F569:L570").Select 
       Selection.ClearContents 
       Range("F569").Select 
   End Sub

   Sub OptionPane() 
       MsgBox (Selection.Address) 
       MsgBox Day(Date) 
       MsgBox Month(Date) 
       MsgBox Year(Date) 
   End Sub
```

Comment: Que macro é essa?

Comment: Poste o código da sua macro

Comment: With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "TEXT;Z:\42\Promessas_diarias_AES_RC_20150304_210000.txt", Destination:=Range _
        (Selection.Address))
        .Name = "Promessas_diarias_AES_RC_20150304_210000"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True

Comment: .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False

Comment: .TextFilePlatform = 1252
        .TextFileStartRow = 5
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = True

Comment: .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = True
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True

Comment: .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
        
    End With
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=6
    Range("F569:L570").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Range("F569").Select
End Sub

Comment: Sub OptionPane()
MsgBox (Selection.Address)
MsgBox Day(Date)
MsgBox Month(Date)
MsgBox Year(Date)
End Sub

Comment: Peço desculpas mas só consegui colocar o código fracionado.

Preciso que após importado o arquivo TXT que é atualizado diariamente ele manda a informação necessaria deixa uma linha em branco e depois na linha abaixo

(9 rows(s) affected) <- Quero que delete esse cara 

Me ajudem por favor

Comment: Não coloque o código em comentários. Edite a pergunta para inserir o código nela! :)

Answer (score 0):

Pelo o que entendi a frase "(9 rows(s) affected)" vem junto com o arquivo .TXT de nome "Promessas_diarias_AES_RC_20150304_210000" que você está tentando importar.
Pelo o que entendi também essa macro foi desenvolvida pelo modo de gravação do Excel.

Bom, você pode pesquisar por outras formas de usar o VBA para fazer a importação do arquivo. Por exemplo usando um laço de repetição e uma condição para parar a importação quando estiver escrito a palavra "rows" na frase.

Mas como não sei o seu nível de VBA, estou enviando o código abaixo para apagar a ultima linha importada. Esse código deve ser inserido após o seu código de importação.

```
    ' Substituir o conteudo entre aspas duplas das variaveis constantes abaixo
    ' para as informações da sua planilha.
    Const _
        colunaDaFrase = "A", _
        nomeAbaExcel = "Plan1"

    ' Abaixo o código está encontrando a ultima linha preenchida na colua
    ' fornecida pela variável acima.
    Dim ultimaLinha As Long
    ultimaLinha = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(nomeAbaExcel).Range(colunaDaFrase & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    ' Abaixo o código está apagando a identificada como "última"
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(nomeAbaExcel).Range(ultimaLinha & ":" & ultimaLinha).Delete Shift:=xlUp
```

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que o melhor seria carregar todos os dados e depois criar uma macro para selecionar as linhas vazias e excluir.

Para identificar o total de linhas você poderia utilizar o código:

```
Total_Linhas = cells(rows.count,1).end(xlup).offset(0,0).row
```

Essa instrução te mostra o total de linhas preenchidas.

Depois varrer a coluna e identificar a linha vazia e excluir.

```
For x = 1 to Total_Linhas  

    if range("A" & x).value = "" then
      range("A" & x).delete shift:= xlUP  
    end if

next x
```